# How to set Expander Direction to slide horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

I know that the `System.Windows.Controls.Expander` is another "headered" content control in WPF just similar to a `System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox`. One advantage is that `Expanders` have the ability to hide its content by collapsing, and showing content by expanding.

My question is, what if I want my `Expander` to slide horizontally from left to right or right to left instead of vertically? and let's say I have the below `Expander`:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel">
    <Expander x:Name="ExportExpander">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="x" Text="Element One"/>
            <Button Name="y" Content="Element Two"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [`ExpandDirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.expander.expanddirection#System_Windows_Controls_Expander_ExpandDirection) property of the `Expander` like this:

```
<Expander x:Name="ExportExpander" ExpandDirection="Right">
```

Also the correct code is like below:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel">
    <Expander x:Name="ExportExpander" ExpandDirection="Right">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="x" Text="Element One"/> <!--Textblock has Text property-->
            <Button Name="y" Content="Element Two"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: +1 for a partial solution + code fix. But this will keep the elements inside the Expander vertically stacked on TOP of each other. I am trying to set the elements BESIDE each other then slide right/left.

Comment: @FirstStep...You could use `Orientation="Horizontal"` of the inner `StackPanel`. Ckeck my updated answer.